# Running script on a remote server in bash working on 1 server, not on the other

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

When I am running this script on 2 servers in hostnames, it succeeds on one of them, but not on the other.

The log output is pretty ugly, so I won't post all of it. Here is part of the bash_history, it also gives a syntax error for fi bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi', because it's executing line by line on the server it's failing on.

Both servers have the same version of Bash:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# See if registry is set to expire updates
# Master script

filename=hostnames
> export.log

while read -r -a line
do
        hostname=${line//\"}
        echo $hostname":" >> export.log
        ssh -t -t $hostname "bash -s" < script.sh >> export.log
done < "$filename"

exit
```

Script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# See if registry is set to expire updates
# Execution script

PATH=/usr/xpg4/bin:$PATH
PARAMETER=Updates
FILE=/etc/.properties

# Code must:
# - Check if FILE exists
# - If the file exists, check if the parameter Updates is set
# - If not set, set to 30.

if [ -f $FILE ];
        then if grep -q $PARAMETER $FILE;
                then echo "File found, parameter already added."
        else
                echo "File found, parameter not found."
                echo "Updates 30" | sudo tee -a $FILE
        fi
else
        echo "File not found."
fi

exit
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's executing line by line on the server it's failing on."? If it's executing in two different ways you have to indicate these to be able to debug the situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess but i would try this

```
filename=hostnames
> export.log

while read -r -a line
do
    hostname=${line//\"}
    echo $hostname":" >> export.log
    ssh -t -t $hostname "bash -s" < script.sh >> export.log &
done < "$filename"

exit
```

Just to make sure you don t get stuck on one server.